# Chord Diagram in Python

Tags: python, chord-diagram

Hi have a DataFrame along those lines:

```
Source   Target    Value     
A        B         10       
A        C         5    
A        D         15
A        E         20
A        F         3
B        A         3
B        G         15
F        D         13
F        E         2
E        A         20
E        D         6
```

And want to draw this Chord Diagram using Python:

[image]

I found this chord diagram in the following link: https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/chord.html. It states that this plot is made using the circlize library (which I believe is an R library). Is there a way to do this in Python as well?

I would also like to be able to choose the color for each element (A to G in my case) and write on the circumference as shown in the example image.

Here is another DataFrame for example with the colors:

```
Name   Color
A      Red
B      Orange
C      Yellow
D      Green
E      Blue
F      Purple
```

Also an arrow tip to help distinguish the source from the target, if possible, as in the example image.

I can't find a ready available library in python that does this for me.

Comment: video from @ScottBoston is not available.

Comment: You can create a chord diagram in d3js using python. See also this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65344303/circular-chord-diagram-in-python/73985381#73985381

Answer (score 5):

Building on @mportes answer,

- The Chord library now is a paid service, included in [plotapi](https://plotapi.com).
- Plotting chord diagrams in plotly seems pretty complicated and the [example](https://plotly.com/python/v3/filled-chord-diagram/) is only for v3.

So the solution that worked best for me is using Holoviews.
[Here](https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Chord.html) is an example plot. I don't know if you can make arrows, but the direction from source to target is easily identifiable because the chords always have the source color.

Comment: HoloViews worked very well for me. Frankly, I was amazed by the capabilities of HoloViews and coding in the Grammar of Graphics framework is a treat. Thank you and upvoted!

Answer (score 3):

The page you share the link to has a **Build your own** section with a link to the [Python Gallery](https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/chord-diagram/). Here you can find three alternative ways to make a chord diagram in Python:

- using the Chord library
- using the Bokeh library
- using the Plotly library

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful! The Bokeh library has deprecated support for chords but HoloViews has taken up from where Bokeh left off and the chord diagrams in HoloViews are a treat - as beautiful and they are elgant and informative. Thanks and upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You can try plotting the chord diagram using the [D3Blocks](https://github.com/d3blocks/d3blocks/) package

> D3Blocks builts on the graphics of d3 javascript (d3js) to create the most visually attractive and useful charts with only a few lines of Python code! The documentation pages contains detailed information about the working of the blocks with many examples.

##### Example from the documentation:

**Sample Input:**

The input dataset is a DataFrame with three column, source, target and weight.

**Code to generate Chord diagram:**

```py
# Load d3blocks
from d3blocks import D3Blocks
#
# Initialize
d3 = D3Blocks(chart='Chord', frame=False)
#
# Import example
df = d3.import_example('energy')
#
# Node properties
d3.set_node_properties(df, opacity=0.2, cmap='tab20')
d3.set_edge_properties(df, color='source', opacity='source')
#
# Show the chart
d3.show()
#
# Make some edits to highlight the Nuclear node
# d3.node_properties
d3.node_properties.get('Nuclear')['color']='#ff0000'
d3.node_properties.get('Nuclear')['opacity']=1
# Show the chart
#
d3.show()
# Make edits to highlight the Nuclear Edge
d3.edge_properties.get(('Nuclear', 'Thermal generation'))['color']='#ff0000'
d3.edge_properties.get(('Nuclear', 'Thermal generation'))['opacity']=0.8
d3.edge_properties.get(('Nuclear', 'Thermal generation'))['weight']=1000
#
# Show the chart
d3.show()
```

**Chord Diagram:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See this post [Creating chord diagram in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65030626/creating-chord-diagram-in-python/74404594#74404594) where I demonstrate how to create a Chord chart using the [D3Blocks library](https://d3blocks.github.io/d3blocks/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try [PlotAPI](https://plotapi.com) (paid) - it's available as a Python package.

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUccbPEv5s8) a video on Chord diagrams from concept to Python code.